# Case class and Linearization of traits

Tags: scala, traits, case-class

Suppose that I want to write a case class `Stepper` as follows:

```
case class Stepper(step: Int) {def apply(x: Int) = x + step}
```

It comes with a nice `toString`implementation:

```
scala> Stepper(42).toString
res0: String = Stepper(42)
```

but it's not really a function:

```
scala> Some(2) map Stepper(2)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Stepper
 required: Int => ?
              Some(2) map Stepper(2)
```

A workaround is to implement the `Function` trait...

```
case class Stepper(step: Int) extends (Int => Int) {def apply(x: Int) = x + step}
```

But then, I can't have for free a nice toString implementation anymore:

```
scala> Stepper(42).toString
res2: java.lang.String = <function1>
```

Then, the question is: can I have the best of these two worlds? Is there a solution where I have the nice `toString` implementation for free *AND* an implementation of trait `Function`. In other words, is there a way to apply the linearization in such a way that `case class` syntaxic sugar is applied at last?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question is not really to do with linearisation. In case-classes `toString` is a method automatically generated by the compiler if and only if `Any.toString` is not overridden in the end-type.

However, the answer is partly to do with linearisation - we need to override `Function1.toString` with the method that would have been generated by compiler if not for the version introduced by `Function1` :

```
trait ProperName extends Product {
  override lazy val toString = scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._toString(this)
}

// now just mix in ProperName and... magic!
case class Stepper(step: Int) extends (Int => Int) with ProperName {
  def apply(x:Int) = x+step
}
```

Then

```
println(Some(2) map Stepper(2))
println(Stepper(2))
```

Will produce

> ```
> Some(4)
> Stepper(2)
> ```

**Update**

Here is a version of `ProperName` trait that doesn't rely on the undocumented API method:

```
trait ProperName extends Product {
  override lazy val toString  = {
    val caseFields = {
       val arity = productArity
       def fields(from: Int): List[Any] =
         if (from == arity) List()
         else productElement(from) :: fields(from + 1)
       fields(0) 
    }
    caseFields.mkString(productPrefix + "(", ",", ")")
  }
}
```

Alternative `toString` implementation is derived from the source code for the original `_toString` method [`scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime._toString`](http://harrah.github.com/browse/samples/library/scala/runtime/ScalaRunTime.scala.html).

Please note that this alternative implementation is still based on the assumption that a case class always extends `Product` trait. Although the latter holds true as of Scala 2.9.0 and is a fact that is known to and relied upon by some members of Scala community it's not formally documented as part of [Scala Language Spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

Comment: Yes, it's not really linearization, but I didn't find any other appropriate name for it. And that was the kind of trick I expected, thanks.

Comment: @Nicolas I understand you very well, I find myself that often times it's difficult to describe a problem exactly when I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: @Vlad: I've always avoided using anything from `scala.runtime` that doesn't show up in the Scala API docs. I agree that this is a clever workaround, but do you really think it's worth it, given that there are equally good solutions that use plain old Scala language features?

Comment: The other solutions require to repat logic again and again in each case. Of course, Vlad solution is not "production ready", but nice. That's why, unti someone provide something as elegant using the standard API, it's accepted. ;)

Comment: And also: so far, it was the only one I didn't have already considered.

Comment: @Travis anyone who is worried about using `scala.runtime` could roll out his own generic `toString` override by looking at the `scala.runtime.RunTime` source http://harrah.github.com/browse/samples/library/scala/runtime/ScalaRunTime.scala.html It will take a little bit more effort, but might shield against potential changes to the API in the future. An alternative approach would be to cover the proposed `toString` override with unit tests and once (and if) it's broken in the future version - 1) create a simple case class 2) compile 3) javap 4) look what generated method looks like

Comment: @Nicolas I think `toString` was included in case classes as a "nice to have" feature that helps when prototyping / debugging / messing around in the REPL. Normally you wouldn't rely on an implementation detail like the name of a class in code to influence the IO of your app, so in production code, you'd *want* to include your own string representation if you need such a thing.

Comment: An acceptable solution might be to change the trait above to an abstract class and pass the name and arg explicitly, i.e. `abstract class Func[T](name: String, arg: T) extends (T => T) { override def toString = name+"("+arg+")" }`

Comment: @LuigiPlinge In production doesn't means that the logic rely on the toString method. Your `Func` require also a lot of repetition (and for that kind of thing, abstract class is definitely a bad answer). And once again, it does not answer my question. I know how to create a toString or to pimp a library, I was just wondering how I can obtain the toString method of a case class even if I add some other traits.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** What about overriding toString?

```
case class Stepper(step: Int) extends (Int => Int) {
  def apply(x: Int) = x + step
  override def toString = "Stepper(" + step + ")"
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know it. but I really don't want to add un apply (imagine it in a DSL).

Comment: The idea was to find something that can be reused, that's why I didn't go into rewriting toString.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an implicit conversion to have `Stepper` treated like a function only when necessary:

```
case class Stepper(step: Int) { def apply(x: Int) = x + step }

implicit def s2f(s: Stepper) = new Function[Int, Int] {
  def apply(x: Int) = s.apply(x)
}
```

Now you get the case class's `toString` when you call `Stepper(42).toString`, but `Some(2) map Stepper(2)` also works as desired.

(Note that I've been more verbose than necessary above to keep the mechanics clear. You can also write `implicit def s2f(s: Stepper) = s.apply _` or any number of other more concise formulations).

Comment: Yes, but building this implicit is more painful than rewriting toString ;)

Comment: @Nicolas: Really? It's 40 characters. This seems much less "painful" than using an undocumented bit of the runtime API.

Comment: It's not a question of number of characters, its a question of adding some "non-dry" code into a class. The `ScalaRuntime` solution is not perfect, is clearly not production ready but goes in a DRY direction. BTW, I was initially comparing it to rewriting toString (see Tal Pressman's answer)

Comment: @Nicolas: I don't think you're going to be able to write a very satisfyingly DSL-ish library without implicits, and in this case the implicit approach is actually arguably cleaner than inheritance: you only need `Function` to make your syntax pretty, so why force it into your class hierarchy?

Comment: No, my point was not the use of implicit. The matter with your solution is taht I have to create a new implicit function each time I want that my class to be considered as a function. Furthermore, addind the `Function` traitz is not only syntaxic, it's only semantic: Instances of my class ARE functions. Finally, the question was not "can I do it withoverriding, implicit or anything else" but "can i got back the toString definition introduced by the case class".